# Error when trying to download reports from APEX APPLICATION - ORA-29273

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I have an apex application where I am able to download a report, designed in JasperStudio, using information stored in Oracle sqldeveloper DB.
The report should be downloaded by a button click, straight to my downloads folder.

This is the PL/SQL code, within a Process called VIEWPersonalInfo, that's supposed to pull the required Report:

```
-- assign value for Application Item
:APP_FILE_NAME := 'Customer_Personal_information' ; --- Name of Report on the Server
:APP_FILE_TYPE := 'PDF' ; --- the file format to be used
:APP_PARM_NAME := 'ID' ; ---- name of the parameter on the server
:APP_PARM_VALUE := :P2_ID; ----Name of the Page Item
-- call GET_REPORT procedure
   GET_REPORT ( p_file_name => :APP_FILE_NAME ,
                p_file_type => :APP_FILE_TYPE ,
                p_paramter_name => :APP_PARM_NAME ,
                p_paramter_value => :APP_PARM_VALUE  ) ;
```

And this is the Procedure called GET_REPORT to aid in the connection to JasperStudio, Done in sqldeveloper:

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE                 GET_REPORT (p_file_name VARCHAR2 ,p_file_type VARCHAR2 ,p_paramter_name VARCHAR2 ,p_paramter_value VARCHAR2 )
IS
  v_blob                 BLOB;
  v_file_name            VARCHAR2 (100) := p_file_name||'.'||p_file_type;
  v_vcContentDisposition VARCHAR2 (100)  := 'inline';

  v_hostname   VARCHAR2(100) := 'IP'; -- your hostname, eg: localhost
  v_port       NUMBER       :=   'port'; -- port for your JasperReports Server, eg: 8081
  v_username   VARCHAR2(100) := 'jasperadmin'; -- jasperreports server username 
  v_password   VARCHAR2(100) := 'jasperadmin'; -- jaspereports server password
  v_jasper_string VARCHAR2(100) := v_username || ';' || v_password;
  v_login_url  VARCHAR2(100) :=  'http://' || v_hostname || ':' || v_port || '/jasperserver/rest/login';
  -- modify below URL before use!
  -- you should modify the line below; change /Pretius/ to your own name
  -- before you add a line try your URL in a web browser
  v_report_url VARCHAR2(100) := 
    'http://' || v_hostname || ':' || v_port || '/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reports/' || v_file_name;
BEGIN
  -- log into jasper server
  v_blob := apex_web_service.make_rest_request_b(
    p_url => v_login_url,
    p_http_method => 'GET',
    p_parm_name => apex_util.string_to_table('j_username;j_password',';'),
    p_parm_value => apex_util.string_to_table(v_jasper_string,';')
  );
  -- download file
  v_blob := apex_web_service.make_rest_request_b(
    p_url => v_report_url,
    p_http_method => 'GET',
    p_parm_name => apex_util.string_to_table(p_paramter_name,';'),
    p_parm_value => apex_util.string_to_table(p_paramter_value,';')
  );
  --OWA_UTIL.mime_header ('application/pdf', FALSE);  -- view your pdf file
  OWA_UTIL.MIME_HEADER( 'application/octet', FALSE ); -- download your pdf file
  HTP.p('Content-Length: ' || DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(v_blob));
  HTP.p('Content-Disposition: ' || v_vcContentDisposition ||'; filename="' || v_file_name || '"');
  OWA_UTIL.http_header_close;
  WPG_DOCLOAD.DOWNLOAD_FILE(v_blob);
  APEX_APPLICATION.STOP_APEX_ENGINE;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE;
END;
```

When I try to download I get the error `ORA-29273: HTTP request failed`.

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

There should be additional error code in error stack; error you posted just shows that *something* went wrong, but the next error says *what* it was.

Based on what you said so far, I suspect it is about

> ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL).

which means that you (actually, your DBA) will have to create one.

Comment: How would I go about making this change? The DB Connection was actually duplicated from a first and the changes were made. This one that's giving the error is Production. The test environment worked fine.

Comment: As I said, you'll need to talk to DBA. They manage ACLs.

Comment: DBA wasn't available. I had to create the new ACL. It worked.

Comment: Ah, OK - you never said you have such a privilege. I'm glad if you fixed it.